# Special Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

**Q . Suppose that we state that a positive integer number  is called “special” if the set 
{1,2,3, . . . ,2016}
can be split into  subsets, all of them with the same number of elements and the same sum of elements.**

a) What are the smallest  > 1 and the largest  < 2016 “special” numbers? Why?

b) Which of the two numbers 336 and 672, if any, is a “special” number? Why?

Comment: Yes but what is a "special" number. The sum or did you mean the set to be {1,2,3,...n} and n to be the "special" number. And what are your thoughts?

Comment: {1,2016}{2,2015}.... splits the set.  So we are done. But... um..m *what* number is special? 2? 2015? 53? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: Is there a "special" significance to identifying the number of subsets $nn$ rather than simply $n$?  Are you trying to restrict the "specialness" of positive integers to two-digit numbers?  To numbers base ten with two equal digits?  Or may $nn$ be any positive integer, so long as the conditions of equal size and sum partitions are achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $nn$ must be a divisor of $2016$, and also of $1+2+\ldots+2016 = 2016 \times 2017/2$, thus a divisor of $1008$.  So $672$ is not special.

To see that $1008$ is special, split into subsets $\{1,2016\},\; \{2,2015\},\; \ldots,\; \{1008, 1009\}$.

Any divisor $d > 1$ of $1008$ is special: split up the $1008$ pairs above into $d$ sets of $1008/d$ pairs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answers

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: What are the smallest  > 1 and the largest  < 2016 “special” numbers? Why?

Comment: and how is 672 not a special number

Comment: Do you know what "divisor" means?